# Unable to compile since last update

Tags: miktex

I updated MiKTeX this morning (08/26) since many binaries were updated. However the update ended with error messages. The new versions, according to MiKTeX Package Manager seem to be installed, but trying to compile  yields error messages about missing  .dlls. Does anyone know what is the problem, and how to solve it? Many, many thanks in advance!

*Edit*: Problem solved. Here's how, if it may help: some .dlls were installed, for a reason I don't understand, in `\MiKTeX\bin` instead of being  installed in `\MiKTeX\bin\x64`. The list of these (in case it could be useful) were:

`MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll`, `__-setup.dll`, `_-trace.dll`, `_-ui-Qt.dll`, `_-utf8wrap.dll` and `_util.dll`

So, I extracted these .dlls from `MiKTeX-runtime-bin-x64.tar.lzma`  and installed them by hand in the correct directory
. After that MiKTeX console worked, and the updater asked to install MiKTeX-runtime-bin-x64.tar.lzma anew, which I did. The six .dlls which I installed by hand were marked as `(old)`, and, I suppose, replaced with those from the updater. Should I delete the ‘old’ .dlls?

I must say I have no idea of why this mess, which may have been purely accidental.

Comment: Missing dll error appears even for compilation of a simple Hello world document? I just updated: no errors for me.

Comment: Renew the package database and then check in the package list (admin) if there are uninstalled packages. If the problem persists make a bug report on the miktex site (with the exact name of the missing .dlls).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the described error does not appear a second time, the problem may have been purely accidental ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was purely accidental